# ServerName on VirtualHost not working in Apache 2.4.6

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost

I have the following VirtualHosts inside /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/domain.com.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
        ServerName www.domain1.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName test.domain2.com
        ServerAdmin admin@domain2.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain2dir
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/domain2.com-error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domain2.com-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName something.domain1.com
        ServerAdmin admin@domain2.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/somethingdir
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/something.domain1.com-error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/something.domain1.com-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

When I access my server via IP, it shows me /var/www/html/; [OK]

When I access my server via something.domain1.com, it shows me/var/www/html/somethingdir; [OK]

But when I access test.domain2.com, it returns me to http://IP/ instead of taking me to /var/www/html/domain2dir.

Why is that?

PS: domain2dir is a wordpress site.

**EDIT:** I changed *DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain2dir* to something other than domain2dir and it works. I think this means that the problem is the wordpress directory, but I'm not sure why.

Running CentOS 7 with Apache 2.4.6 and PHP 7.2.9.

Comment: Check your WordPress settings.

Comment: The WordPress is not mine, it's only hosted here. I asked the guy in charge and he has no idea why this is happening, so I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: wordpress sucks at this type of thing. During installation you specify what hostname it should use and after that anything else just gives chaos.

Comment: I asked him to change inside WordPress so it would point to test.domain2.com, but when I try to access it via http://test.domain2.com, it redirects me to http://IP/. And if I try with http://IP/domain2dir/, it redirects me to http://test.domain2.com/domain2dir/. No idea why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone with the same problem, it was inside WordPress's database. 
It was pointing to http://IP/domain2dir/etc.etc.etc, so every time Apache redirected to that particular directory, WordPress redirected back to http://IP/.
The solution is to change your http://IP/dir/ inside a few tables to http://domain/.